# Dismiss keyboard in custom keyboard ios8 not working

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I'm having some trouble with the custom keyboard extension in ios8 with the dismiss keyboard method.

I'm calling it with :

```
[self dismissKeyboard];
```

It compiles OK, but when I press my dismiss button it crashes and open the normal keyboard. In the console I can only see the next few lines:

> 2014-08-25 17:38:50.147 customkeyboards[2678:5567685] plugin
>   com.customkeyboards interrupted 2014-08-25 17:38:51.248
>   customkeyboards[2678:5567651] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error
>   Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)"
>   UserInfo=0x7a8dd4c0 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

I'm using ios 8 beta 6 and running it into the emulator. The same happens in the device with the lastest beta (ios5)

Comment: I'm getting this error before the keyboard even loads. Looks like Xcode is crashing

Comment: Same issue here when I tap on one of my keys on the keyboard

Comment: get the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay! the following code solved my problem!    
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    self.inputView.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    [self.inputView removeFromSuperview ];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview ];
    for (UIView *v in [self.inputView subviews]){
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
    for (UIView *v in [self.view subviews]){
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
    
     [self dismissKeyboard];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem, here is the code that solved it! Good luck!

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];

self.inputView.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
self.view.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
[self.inputView removeFromSuperview ];
[self.view removeFromSuperview ];
for (UIView *v in [self.inputView subviews]){
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}
for (UIView *v in [self.view subviews]){
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}

 [self dismissKeyboard];
```